# Create Bitmap object from array

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have an array like `byte[] pixels`. Is there any way to create a `bitmap` object from that `pixels` without copying data? I have a small graphics library, when I need to display image on `WinForms` window I just copy that data to a `bitmap` object, then I use draw method. Can I avoid this copying process? I remember I saw it somewhere, but maybe my memory is just bad.

Edit: I tried this code and it works, but is this safe?

```
byte[] pixels = new byte[10 * 10 * 4];

pixels[4] = 255; // set 1 pixel
pixels[5] = 255;
pixels[6] = 255;
pixels[7] = 255;

// do some tricks
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

// create a new bitmap.
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap (10, 10, 4*10, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, pointer);

Graphics grp = this.CreateGraphics ();
grp.DrawImage (bmp, 0, 0);

pixels[4+12] = 255; // add a pixel
pixels[5+12] = 255;
pixels[6+12] = 255;
pixels[7+12] = 255;

grp.DrawImage (bmp, 0, 40);
```

Comment: This is somewhat related I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580130/high-speed-performance-of-image-filtering-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a constructor that takes a pointer to raw image data:

[Bitmap Constructor (Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx)

Example:

```
byte[] _data = new byte[]
{
    255, 0, 0, 255, // Blue
    0, 255, 0, 255, // Green
    0, 0, 255, 255, // Red
    0, 0, 0, 255,   // Black
};

var arrayHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(_data,
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);

var bmp = new Bitmap(2, 2, // 2x2 pixels
    8,                     // RGB32 => 8 bytes stride
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb,
    arrayHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
);

this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
this.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

Comment: When I try to draw newBitmap it throws Access Violation :/ It says it should be called from Paint method (PaintEventArgs).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

I don't think these method calls will do any copying, as nothing in the MSDN indicate such: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a84386f

Comment: A lot of people seem to miss the fact that the FromStream method expects that the stream will contain the bitmap header info along with the RGB or pixel values.