# How to Convert an RGB Image to a Gray scale 2D double Array in C# as Fast as posible

Tags: c#, arrays, image, matlab, performance

I have a Problem to Convert an RGB Image to a 2D double array that each element is between 0 to 1 in C#. I used a function to read each pixel of an Image then  average and scale them to convert it into a 2d array. but this code is too slow. for a 36 Mega Pixel image it takes about 30 seconds in comparison with MATLAB that it takes just 0.5 second. since it is vital for my project to increase the speed of processing I don't know to do it

```
public static double[,] Image2Matrix(Bitmap Image)
    {
        int nR = Image.Size.Height;
        int nC = Image.Size.Width;

        double   S=0 ;
        Color C;

        double[,] M = new double[nR, nC];


        for (int i = 0; i < nR; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nC; j++)
            {
                C= Image.GetPixel(j, i);

                M[i, j] = (Convert.ToDouble(C.R) + Convert.ToDouble(C.B)+Convert.ToDouble(C.G)) / (3*255);  
            }
        }



        return M;
    }
```

Comment: Matlab is multi-threaded. You could try that.

Comment: I would suggest using [Bitmap.LockBits Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if you get a performance boost. Moreover, you dont need to cpnvert each R,G,B to `double` keep them as byte and convert them to `double` at the last step. If these two are not enough for speeding up enough yr Parallel.Foreach

Comment: @Emrah. I'm pretty sure that's correct, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of `LockBits` and unsafe code it's possible to speed things up about 100 times.

Solution mostly cribbed [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580170/14357).

```
public static double[,] Image2Matrix(Bitmap image)
{
    if (image == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("image");
    var data = image.LockBits(
                  new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), 
                  ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
    double[,] matrix = new double[image.Height, image.Width];
    try
    {
        unsafe
        {
            byte* ptr = (byte*)data.Scan0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < data.Width; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = (ptr[0] + ptr[1] + ptr[2]) / (3d * 255);
                    ptr += 3;
                }

                ptr += data.Stride - data.Width * 3;
            }
            return matrix;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        image.UnlockBits(data);
    }
}
```

A quick benchmark:

```
spender's method took : 59ms
sadegh's method took : 5162ms
arrays are identical : True
spender's method took : 66ms
sadegh's method took : 5133ms
arrays are identical : True
spender's method took : 68ms
sadegh's method took : 5168ms
arrays are identical : True
```

By parallelizing the summing, this goes even faster on my machine. YMMV.

```
public static double[,] Image2Matrix2(Bitmap image)
{
    if (image == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("image");
    var data = image.LockBits(
                  new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), 
                  ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
    double[,] matrix = new double[image.Height, image.Width];
    try
    {
        unsafe
        {
            byte* scan0 = (byte*)data.Scan0;
            Parallel.For(0, data.Height, i => {
                for (int j = 0; j < data.Width; j++)
                {
                    byte* ptr = scan0 + (i * data.Stride + j * 3);
                    matrix[i, j] = (ptr[0] + ptr[1] + ptr[2]) / (3d * 255);
                }
            });
            return matrix;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        image.UnlockBits(data);
    }
}
```

```
spender's method took : 22ms
sadegh's method took : 5284ms
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the size of the image in pixels? Op said 36 MegePixels took 30seconds

Comment: Biggish, but obvs smaller that OPs image. 4600x2700

Comment: Thanks very much. I used your latter codes. it was wonderful. for my computer my code takes about 30 seconds but your code was surprising it just takes about 0.15 second.